# PHP append content to a file (reading/writing of a file)

Tags: php, get

I'm still rather new to PHP and I'm working on a trying to do something kinda like this;

`down.php?days=numberHere` take that number and write it to a file and then display the file in a spot, I know how to display the file but I'm not really sure how to write to the file with GET if someone could point me in a direction to learn or help me out that'd be great, I've looked around for a few days and haven't seen anything that would help

Thanks

Edit:

I've re-read my question and some of the answers, and I don't know if I was really clear in what I'm trying to accomplish; Basically, If Cooldowns.txt has "10" and ?days=7, then cooldowns.txt needs to become 17 instead of adding the numbers to the file

---

**Update:** I've come up with something like that based on the replies to my question, I'm wondering if there's a way to make it add the get ? (IE get = 1 + whatever the file already has, so if the file has 25 and get = 1 file becomes 26)

Comment: See the `file_put_contents` function.

Comment: [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for writing and [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for reading

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, I'll look into it now :)

Comment: I added edits including more detail based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From quote:

> I've come up with something like that based on the replies to my
>   question, I'm wondering if there's a way to make it add the get ? (IE
>   get = 1 + whatever the file already has, so if the file has 25 and get
>   = 1 file becomes 26)

```
// Retrieve data from file.txt and type cast it as an integer
$current = (int) file_get_contents('file.txt');
// Increment $current, equivalent to $current=$current+1;
$current++;
// Write back
file_put_contents('file.txt', $current);
```

Comment: `// Increment $current, equivalent to $current=$current+1;`  would I be able to do something like $current=$current+$_get[days]?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Or even `$current += $_GET['days']`.  Variables and keys are case sensitive in PHP.  Defining `[days]` actually looks for a constant named `days`, you want it interpreted as a string.

Comment: Hey there, I've accepted your answer as most useful as without your assistance I would still be googling :D! I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: No problem, if you want to see more on the operators (like +=, or ++) check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php.  The += is an assignment operator.  The php.net site has a lot of useful reads and examples in their manual pages.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
// Try this code
if(isset($_GET['days'])){
    $number=(int)$_GET['days']."\n";
    $file='file.txt';
/* 
/The existing data in file is preserved.
/File pointer starts at the end of the /file.
/Creates a new file if the file doesn't exist
*/
    $fopen=fopen($file,'a+');
    $fwrite=fwrite($fopen, $number);
    echo readfile($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: I ran this code and this seems to be the output: http://prntscr.com/6yahim it's just writing the number to file and appending it, but I don't understand the "30" ? edit; I think the `30` is the file size?

Comment: @RoXes , 30 is file size ,Use this code echo **file_get_contents( $file);**  replace with **echo readfile($file);**

Answer (score 1):

Use `file_put_contents()`, read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
file_put_contents("file.txt", "My Content");
```

(EDITED) If want to append to a file's current content, use `FILE_APPEND` constant and pass it as third parameter of the function:

```
file_put_contents("file.txt", "\r\n" . "My Content", FILE_APPEND);
```

**mode**    **Description**

> 'r'   Open for reading only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file.
>
> 'r+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the
>   beginning of the file.
>
> 'w'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'w+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the
>   beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the
>   file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a'   Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the
>   file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a+'  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end
>   of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'x'   Create and open for writing only; place the file pointer at the
>   beginning of the file. If the file already exists, the fopen() call
>   will fail by returning FALSE and generating an error of level
>   E_WARNING. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it. This is
>   equivalent to specifying O_EXCL|O_CREAT flags for the underlying
>   open(2) system call.
>
> 'x+'  Create and open for reading and writing; otherwise it has the
>   same behavior as 'x'.
>
> 'c'   Open the file for writing only. If the file does not exist, it is
>   created. If it exists, it is neither truncated (as opposed to 'w'),
>   nor the call to this function fails (as is the case with 'x'). The
>   file pointer is positioned on the beginning of the file. This may be
>   useful if it's desired to get an advisory lock (see flock()) before
>   attempting to modify the file, as using 'w' could truncate the file
>   before the lock was obtained (if truncation is desired, ftruncate()
>   can be used after the lock is requested).
>
> 'c+'  Open the file for reading and writing; otherwise it has the same
>   behavior as 'c'.

But PHP also allows a lower level of file I/O, by using fopen() function, it returns you a file descriptor which allows various modes of I/O:

```
$fd = fopen("file.txt");
```

Read about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

You then pass the file descriptor to other f* family functions:

```
fwrite($fd, "Content");
```

The $mode parameter of `fopen()` function helps you selecting how to read/write:

According to the table above taken from `fopen()` documentation on php.net (link given), you can use mode `a`:

```
fopen("file.txt", "a");
```

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for the reply! I've come up with something like that based on the replies to my question, I'm wondering if there's a way to make it add the get ? (IE get = 1 + whatever the file already has, so if the file has 25 and get = 1 file becomes 26)

Comment: That's a pretty inefficient way to append.  You should use the flag FILE_APPEND.

Comment: @MostafaTalebi, you still have the inefficient append in there.  Look at [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Comment: Sorry but May I know how do you say fopen() with $mode set to 'a' is inefficient?